# 'SVC' object has no attribute 'best_params_'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svc

```
def ParamSelection(X, Y, nfolds): 
    Cs = [0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100]
    degrees = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    param_grid = {'C': Cs, 'degree' : degrees}
    grid_search = GridSearchCV(svm.SVC(kernel = 'poly'), param_grid, cv = nfolds)
    grid_search = svm.SVC(gamma='scale')
    grid_search.fit(X, Y)
    grid_search.best_params_
    return grid_search.best_params_
ParamSelection(trainX, trainY, 10)
```

> AttributeError: 'SVC' object has no attribute 'best_params_'

I'm getting the above error. What should I do? Can you help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You re-assigned `GridSearch` to `svm`, so your `GridSearch` object is not the `sklearn` object. Just delete this line:

```
grid_search = svm.SVC(gamma='scale')
```

Then it should run fine. You'll get a deprecation warning, so set the `gamma` parameter when instantiating `SVC()`:

```
grid_search = GridSearchCV(svm.SVC(kernel = 'poly', gamma='scale'), param_grid, cv = nfolds)
```

Comment: if i delete this line, I'm getting this error; FutureWarning: The default value of gamma will change from 'auto' to 'scale' in version 0.22 to account better for unscaled features. Set gamma explicitly to 'auto' or 'scale' to avoid this warning.
  "avoid this warning.", FutureWarning)

Comment: That's not an error. That's a deprecation warning. It just means: _You can do this operation, but when we update the library, you won't be able to anymore_. I edited the answer to account for it though.

Comment: ParamSelection(trainX, trainY, 10) call this function but ı cant get any output

Comment: did you print the results? did you assign them to a new variable? either way, it's best to keep only one question per thread on S/O.